# Why do I get an error saying "You cannot serialize or deserialize PDO instances" when I include one file into another?

Tags: php, pdo, phpunit

Say I have two php files (they are fictional but display the problem). The first one func.php contains a function, and the second one funcTest.php is for testing the function.
First:

```
<?php


   require_once "pdo_set/pdo.php";
   $db_name = "db";
   try {
       $pdo = new PDO("$driver:host=$host;dbname=$db_name;charset=$charset", $db_user, $db_pass, 
       $options);
   } catch (Exception $ex) {
       echo "<script>alert('Error')</script>";
       die();
   }
    function func(int $a, int $b, $data) {
          echo "$a, $b, $data";
          return $a + $b;
    }
```

Second:

```
<?php
    require_once "PHPUnit/Autoload.php";
    require "func.php";
    use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
    
    $data = "Some data";

    var_dump($data);
    
    final class funcTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
        public function testFunc() {
            $this->assertEquals(3, func(1, 2, $data));
        }
    }
```

When I run test using PHPUnit, I get this error:

> There was 1 error:
>
> 1. FuncTest::testFunc PDOException: You cannot serialize
>    or unserialize PDO instances

**Why do I get the error. How to workaround this?**

**P.S. I've found many qeustions on forums including SO about problems with "PDO serialize deserialize", but none of them helped me. So please DO NOT mark it as a duplicate.**

Comment: *"P.S. I've found many qeustions on forums including SO about problems with "PDO serialize deserialize", but none of them helped me. So please DO NOT mark it as a duplicate."* - could you please link those you found?

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal they don't relate to my question. But OK: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700702/pdoexception-you-cannot-serialize-or-unserialize-pdo-instances https://habr.com/ru/post/120661/  https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads/issues/209 https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/977460

Comment: None of them relate to what I encountered with